# Postgres Select Query - grouping same objects

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Consider query as below:

```
select 
    row_to_json(t) 
from (
    select 
        tablex.id, 
        valuetable.id as "valuetable.id",
        valuetable.val_string as "valuetable.val_string" 
    FROM TableA AS tablex 
    INNER JOIN TableB AS valuetable ON tablex.id = valuetable.id  
    WHERE tablex.code= '123')t;
```

This when hit from postgres return response as

```
{id:111,valuetable.id:222,valuetable.val_string:"xx"}
```

When I run the same query:

```
select 
    tablex.id,
    valuetable.id as "valuetable.id",
    valuetable.val_string as "valuetable.val_string" 
FROM TableA AS tablex 
INNER JOIN TableB AS valuetable ON tablex.id = valuetable.id  
WHERE tablex.code= '123'
```

with sequelize,it would respond as

When I run the same query:

```
{id:111,valuetable:{id:222,val_string:"xx"}}
```

which is expected.

Could you please favour on how to generate such response from postgres too, or would any manipulation be required from java end?

Comment: if you feel that this handling of the FROM clause is erroneous in row_to_json(), then you should probably take it up on the pgsql-hackers mailing list.   I actually agree with the PostgreSQL interpretation logically.

Comment: `row_to_json` will never created nested attributes. It is defines as turning a row into a single JSON value where every column of the row is one key in the JSON value. How should that function know which parts should be nested?

Comment: I agree with your point. I ain't sure how to write query that generates such response.

Comment: I think you should be using **json_build_object** instead of row_to_json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of row_to_json, try using **json_build_object**, like so:

```
select 
   json_build_object(
       'id', tablex.id, 
       'valuetable', json_build_object(
           'id', valuetable.id,
           'val_string', valuetable.val_string)
   )
FROM TableA AS tablex 
INNER JOIN TableB AS valuetable ON tablex.id = valuetable.id  
WHERE tablex.code= '123'
```

Comment: Exactly this is the method i adopted then.